# Вопрос про специализацию и шаблонны классы со статическими данными

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

допустим есть шаблонный класс:

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    static T t;
    static T foo()
    {
        return t;
    }
};
```

В чём разница между такой инициализацией статического члена `t`

```
double X<double>::t = 5.0f;
```

и такой инициализацией со специализацией класса (или статического члена !?) ?

```
template<>
double X<double>::t = 5.0f;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Оба синтаксиса формально корректны, но первый не применим в данном контексте.

У вас есть возможность использовать четыре относительно "похожих" синтаксиса за пределами определения самого шаблонного класса

```
// 1
template<typename T> T X<T>::t;
// "Общее" определение статического члена.
// Является определением независимо от наличия инициализатора.

// 2
template<> double X<double>::t = 3;
// Явная специализация статического члена для `T == double`.
// Является определением только при наличии инициализатора. Без инициализатора
// является просто объявлением.
// Определения, предоставленные методом 1, не распространяются на явные
// специализации, т.е. определение для явной специализации требуется
// предоставить отдельно.

// 3
template double X<double>::t;
// Явное инстанцирование статического члена для `T == double`.
// Не допускает указания инициализатора. 
// Может выполняться только после выполнения определения или явной 
// специализации. В последнем случае - не имеет никакого эффекта.

// 4
double X<double>::t = 3;
// Определение статического члена явной специализации.
// Является определением независимо от наличия инициализатора.
// Требует, чтобы явная специализация шаблона класса была определена выше.
```

Все эти синтаксические конструкции единообразно распространяются и на объявления методов класса. В данном случае, однако, мы говорим именно о статических данных.

---

Таким образом ваше первое объявление будет являться корректным в том и только в том случае, если оно следует за определением явной специализации шаблона класса `X` для `T == double`

```
template<typename T> class X
{
public:
    static T t;
};

template<> class X<double>
{
public:
    static double t;
};

double X<double>::t = 5.0f;
```

Но без явной специализации шаблона класса, как в вашем конкретном примере, такое объявление неуместно.

Answer (score 2):

Да, разница существенна, запись `double X<double>::t = 5.0f;` является невалидной и вызовет [ошибку компиляции](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qyDh30FKzjJlPPCE).

Comment: ну вы же не думаете что я без тестового запуска задаю такой вопрос ?

Comment: @ampawd именно так я и думаю

Comment: зря так думаете, потому как обе проходят компиляцию безо всяких проблем, по крайней мере компилятор от microsoft в MSVC 2015 не ругается

Comment: @ampawd Может быть, но, тем не менее, это некорректный синтаксис. Можете отправить багрепорт в MS Connect

Comment: а что означает вторая запись с `template<>` это специализация класса или статического члена ?

Comment: @ampawd: Разумеется, это специализация только члена `t`.

Comment: @Ant а что есть специализация члена ? я так понимаю это `variable template` которое появилось с с++14 ?

Comment: Это специализация только для конкретного члена класса `X`, все остальные поля и функции будут такими же, как и у других вариантов класса, а `t` будет отличаться. И нет, это не `variable template`

Comment: @ampawd: Специализация отдельного члена существует в С++ с начала времен (с С++98). Члены шаблонного класса - это отдельные шаблоны, живущие своей отдельной жизнью. Их всегда можно было специализировать отдельно.

Comment: Это не может не вызвать ошибку компиляции