# Необходимость template<> для объявления полной специализации шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, история

Почему для объявления полной специализации шаблонного класса используется синтаксис `template<>`? Зачем он нужен, если можно использовать просто название класса со специализируемыми типами?

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос, напишите свой вариант синтаксиса шаблонов, который Вы бы хотели видеть. Но и без этого: вариантов синтаксиса можно придумать очень много и все они будут семантически эквивалентны.

Answer (score 1):

В С++ синтаксис `template<> class SomeClass<аргументы>` объявляет совершено *новую* сущность - *явную специализацию* шаблонного класса. Хоть явная специализация и имеет связь с "главным" шаблоном, ее содержимое (определение) является совершенно независимым от главного шаблона.

А синтаксис `class SomeClass<аргументы>` просто ссылается на *уже существующую* сущность - на специализацию какого-то уже объявленного шаблонного класса `SomeClass` для данного набора аргументов.

У этих синтаксисов совершено разные цели: объявление новой сущности vs. ссылка на уже ранее объявленную сущность.

Также, когда речь идет об объявлениях специализаций *членов* классов, наличие или отсутствие `template <>` также приводит к серьезным различиям в интерпретации таких объявлений (хотя суть различия остается та же). См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/934161/182825

Тут можно попытаться изобрести какой-то набор автоматических правил, которые, возможно, позволили бы компилятору самому разобраться, что именно мы хотим сделать в каждом конкретном контексте. Однако в С++ традиционно введение новых сущностей делается явно и для этого выделен отдельный синтаксис *объявления*. Для явных специализаций этот отдельный синтаксис - это именно синтаксис начинающийся с `template <>`.

Answer (score 1):

Изначально полную специализацию действительно объявляли без `template<>`, т.е.

```
template<typename T>
struct A {

};

struct A<int> {

};
```

, однако в стандарт вошёл именно вариант с `template<>` из-за неоднозначностей (ambiguities) в более сложных случаях полных специализаций. Например:

```
// №1
template<typename T>
struct A {
    template<typename G>
    struct B {
        static int x;
    };
};

// №2
template<>
template<typename G>
struct A<unsigned>::B {
    static unsigned x;
};

// №3
template<>
template<>
unsigned A<unsigned>::B<unsigned>::x;

// №4
template<>
struct A<long> {
    template<typename G>
    struct B {
        static long x;
    };
};

// №5
template<>
long A<long>::B<long>::x;
```

Здесь №2 - специализация члена шаблонного класса `A` для типа `unsigned`, №4 - полная специализация шаблонного класса `A` для типа `long`, №3 - специализация члена шаблонного класса `A<unsigned>::B` для типа `unsigned`, №5 - то же, что и №3 для типов `long`, но так как присутствует полная специализация №4, в №5 только 1 `template<>` в отличие от 2 `template<>` в №3. Если бы `template<>` отсутствовали, то специализации №3 и №5 были бы неотличимы.