# Как определить специализацию члена шаблонного класса с инициализацией конструктором по умолчанию?

Tags: c++, c++11

Как **определить** специализацию члена шаблонного класса с инициализацией конструктором по умолчанию?

Следующая программа не вызывает конструктор по умолчанию, как хотелось бы:

```
#include <iostream>


struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "Default constructor\n";
    };

    A(const A&) = delete;
};

template<typename T>
struct B {
    static T x;
};

template<>
A B<A>::x; // не вызывает конструктор


int main() {
}
```

Comment: Хотя в тегах почему-то стоит древний с++98, в самом вопросе используется `= delete` из С++11, так что я подразумеваю, что вопрос все-таки по современному С++

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/934161/182825. Вариант номер 2: "Явная специализация статического члена. **Является определением только при наличии инициализатора**". У вас инициализатор отсутствует. В вашем случае нужно `{}` или `= {}`.

Answer (score 2):

В коде вопроса `A B<A>::x;` является объявлением. Для того чтобы **определить** это поле необходимо использовать синтаксис инициализации списком:

```
template<>
A B<A>::x{};
```

> **17.8.3 Explicit specialization [temp.expl.spec]**
>   14 An explicit specialization of a static data member of a template or an explicit specialization of a static data member template is a definition if the declaration includes an initializer; otherwise, it is a declaration. [Note: The definition of a static data member of a template that requires default-initialization must use a braced-init-list
>   `template<> X Q<int>::x; // declaration`
>   `template<> X Q<int>::x (); // error: declares a function`
>   `template<> X Q<int>::x { }; // definition`
>   —end note ]