# Специализация класса со статическим членом

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны

Делаю шаблон класса.
В шаблонном классе некоторые реализации (в зависимости от типа должны отличаться)
В каждом таком классе должен быть статический объект этого класса.

Взял код из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/934161/219358)

```
template<typename T> class X
{
public:
    static T t;
};

template<> class X<double>
{
public:
    static double t;
};

double X<double>::t = 5.0f;
```

В этом примере статическая переменная не экземпляр самого класса, но сути это не меняет.
Как только я подключаю заголовочный файл с этим кодом 2 двум cpp фпйлам проекта, вылезает ошибка:
**multiple definition of `X::t'**

Это и логично, ведь реализация статического члена обычно делается отдельно в cpp файле. Но с другимы шаблонами это работает. К примеру собирается нормально такой код:

```
template<typename T>
class C{
public:
    T t;
    static int st;
};
template<typename T>
int C<T>::st;

template<typename T>
class C<T*>{
public:
    T* t;
    static int st;
};
template<typename T>
int C<T*>::st;
```

И успешно работает с двумя cpp файлами даже если использовать один и тот же тип в шаблоне.
В чем же дело? И как сделать рабочим первый пример?
Делать отдельный cpp файл со всеми нужными реализациями шаблона или статической переменной не предлагайте. Как я узнаю какие типы мне понадобятся наперед?
Использую c++11

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
template<> class X<double>
{
public:
    inline static double t = 5.0f;
};
```

Ну, или перенесите определение в один из .cpp-файлов, поскольку это уже никак не шаблон...

Comment: А помогло. Просто не там пытался inline поставить

Comment: Но главное хотелось бы понять эту теорию. Что конкретно значит inline  в этом случае.  И как линкер избавляется от 2х экземпляров. А если они как inline  функции просто сгенерены 2 раза, то почему изменение переменной в одном файле меняет её в другом.

Comment: inline генерирует единственный экземпляр. Как именно - дело компилятора, но, думаю, что генерируется в каждом объектнике, но помечается соответствующим образом, так что линковщик из них просто делает один экземпляр.

Comment: Ещё нюанс. Код должен работать для c++11 а этот inline вызывает **warning: inline variables are only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’**

Comment: Тогда способ второй — "*перенесите определение в один из .cpp-файлов, поскольку это уже никак не шаблон*".

Comment: Что конкретно перенести? Я понятия не имею какие типы T будут использоваться. Разве что сделать сложный макрос, который будет делать такую специализацию в cpp, но это сузит использование шаблона только в глобальной области, а если хочется в некой функции достучаться до этого класса, то или прописывать его в двух местах или облом.  А главное я не понимаю почему один способ специализации работает, а другой нет.

Comment: Вот эту строку `double X<double>::t = 5.0f;` при использовании `X<double>`. Или вы его собираетесь использовать, не зная об этом? :)

Comment: Да я и говорю, не знаю зараенее. Это деталька в библиотеке.  И среди типов будут и пользовательские классы, не только простые типы, которые при желании можно все перечислить.

Comment: Вот тогда тот, кто будет использовать вашу библиотеку с типом `double` *и старым компилятором*, пусть и записывает строку в .cpp-файл.

Comment: Я уже привык, что разница между стандартами в мелком удобстве. А в этом случае получается невозможность реализовать без перехода к другому подходу к задаче. Переложить ответственность на тех программистов, которые будут использовать это уже совсем другой подход. Неужели нет способа пусть громоздкого?

Comment: Я его не знаю..